# Combining two codes with a mousePressed-event processing

Tags: java, copy, boolean, mouseevent, processing

My problem is following: 
I wrote a code and managed to display an image when i click on a rectangle (with the loadImage-fuction). The rectangle serves as a button that I want to replace with an image later.
But i actually don't just want an image to be displayed when the button is clicked. I want to call a code, to copy an image onto another:

```
public static int SQUARE_WIDTH = 30;
public static int SQUARE_HEIGHT = 30;
PImage img1,img2, img3;
void setup() {
  size(670, 943);
  img1 = loadImage("white.png");
  img2 = loadImage("hase.jpg");
  img3= loadImage("ohrring.jpg");
  image(img1,0,0);
}
void draw() {
if(mousePressed) 
      copy(img2, 
              constrain(mouseX-SQUARE_WIDTH/2,0,width), 
              constrain(mouseY-SQUARE_HEIGHT/2,0,height), 
              SQUARE_WIDTH,SQUARE_HEIGHT, 
              constrain(mouseX-SQUARE_WIDTH/2,0,width), 
              constrain(mouseY-SQUARE_HEIGHT/2,0,height), 
              SQUARE_WIDTH,SQUARE_HEIGHT);
}
```

The copy-code doesn't simply copy an image, it uses the mouse as a brush! When you "draw" on an area, the image shows with the "strokes" of the brush pixel after pixel!
[processing.org/reference/copy_.html](http://processing.org/reference/copy_.html)

I happen to have huge problems when I want to combine this one with my main code:

```
int rectX, rectY;  
int rectSize = 90;   
boolean rectOver = false;
color rectHighlight;
color currentColor, baseColor;
color rectColor;
public static int SQUARE_WIDTH = 30;
public static int SQUARE_HEIGHT = 30;
PImage img1,img2, img3;


void setup() {
  size(670, 943);
  rectColor = color(0);
  rectX = width/2-rectSize-10;
  rectY = height/2-rectSize/2;
  baseColor = color(102);
  currentColor = baseColor;



  img1 = loadImage("frida.jpg");
  img2 = loadImage("hase.jpg");
  img3 = loadImage("white.png");
    background(img3);

}
  void draw() {
  update(mouseX, mouseY);

  if (rectOver) {
    fill(rectHighlight);
  } else {
    fill(rectColor);
  }
  stroke(255);
  rect(rectX, rectY, rectSize, rectSize);
  }

void update(int x, int y) {
  if ( overRect(rectX, rectY, rectSize, rectSize) ) {
    rectOver = true;
  }else {
    rectOver = false;
  }

}
void mousePressed() {

   if (rectOver) {
  background(img2);
}
}
boolean overRect(int x, int y, int width, int height)  {
  if (mouseX >= x && mouseX <= x+width && 
      mouseY >= y && mouseY <= y+height) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }

}
```

Theoretically I got the tip to set a boolean in mousePressed() to do the copy-operation in draw(), and then to check this boolean in draw(): if set (true) it shall do the copy. But I'm unfortunately not the brightest star in the programming-sky , so could anybody show me what this part is supposed to look like? Of course, I'm open to other suggestions how to solve this problem!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are looking for. If you want to copy an image you don't need to call a function to copy an image, you can simply invoke the = sign and the image will be copied.

In my example code buttonImage is the image on the button. Whenever you don't want an image on the button assign it the following way:

```
buttonImage = null;
```

If you want to have an image instead of the rectangle do the following:

```
buttonImage = yourImage;
buttonImage.resize(w, h); //fit it on the button.
```

I think this is what you want to achieve?

```
PImage buttonImage;

void setup()
{
}
void draw()
{
  if(buttonImage == null || buttonImage.width < 2) rect(x, y, w, h);
  else image(buttonImage, x, y);
}

void mouseReleased()
{
  if(mouseX > x && mouseX < x + w && mouseY > y && mouseY < y + h)
  {
    //copy any image onto the buttonImage
    buttonImage = loadImage("newPath.png"); //update / overwrite image
    buttonImage.resize(w, h); //fit it on the button
  }
}
```

x and y are the position of the button, w and h are the width and the height of the button in my example.

EDIT:
Ok, so basically you want to have a white background and you want to scrap it using your tool so an image appears? I'm still not 100% sure of what you're asking, but if that is the case try this:
I used img.get() instead of img.copy(), because it has less parameters to deal with. I really hoped i understood this correctly, if not maybe link a video to something similar? I have a hard time understanding what you want.

The toolSelected integer is a counter to which tool you are using. Depending on its value, it is executing a different code.

My code:

```
PImage img1;
int toolSelected = 0; //Normal tool;
int widthOfBrush = 20; //Now you are drawing 20x20

int buttonX = 200;
int buttonY = 200;
int buttonW = 40;
int buttonH = 20;

void setup()
{
  size(640, 480);
  background(255);
  img1 = loadImage("yourImg.png");
  img1.resize(width, height); //Fit it on processing screen
}
void draw()
{
  if(toolSelected == 0) {}//other tool
  //Instead of using copy we will be using buttonImage.get(x, y, w, h) --> makes more sense
  if(toolSelected == 1 && mousePressed)
  {
    float yourX = mouseX;
    float yourY = mouseY;
    yourX -= floor(widthOfBrush / 2);
    yourY -= floor(widthOfBrush / 2);
    //scale & copy:
    PImage brushImage = img1.get((int)yourX, (int)yourY, widthOfBrush * (width / img1.width), widthOfBrush * (width / img1.width)); //Draw the image at your destination
    image(brushImage, mouseX, mouseY);
  }

  stroke(0);
  fill(255);
  rect(buttonX, buttonY, buttonW, buttonH);  
}

void mouseReleased()
{
  if (mouseX > buttonX && mouseX < buttonX + buttonW && mouseY > buttonY && mouseY < buttonY + buttonH)
  {
    //copy any image onto the buttonImage
    //buttonImage = loadImage("newPath.png"); //update / overwrite image
    toolSelected = 1; //Our tool is the image brush now.
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer but this isn't exactly what I want to achieve! My copy-code doesn't simply copy an image, it uses the mouse as a brush! When you "draw" on an area, the image shows with the "strokes" of the brush pixel after pixel!
https://www.processing.org/reference/copy_.html
I try to explain what I want to achieve in steps!

1. Display of a button on the canvas
2. When the button is clicked, the code to copy an image gets activated, so that you can now "draw" that image on the canvas

Comment: I edited my answer. Is this what you want? Or do you simply want an image drawing tool, where instead of a brush you draw an image on the screen. If that is the case simply change: if(toolSelected == 1 && mousePressed) image(img1, mouseX, mouseY)  and also remove the img1.resize() part.